# Knitting error when converting to pdf on rstudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I keep getting this error when I try to knit to PDF using R Markdown. It has worked before, and I tried installing the package contrib.url but it says it is not available for my version. Any suggestions?

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror calls : <Anonymous> ... with visible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages -> contrib.url Execution halted
```

Comment: If you have a `install.packages()` line in your Rmd document, you should remove it. If you don't, you'd need to provide more information in order to help you.

Comment: What package is `contrib.url `?  Or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

The error usually comes when you don't set a mirror in the `install.packages` command. You probably have a call to `install.packages` somewhere in your markdown document.

Try the following:

```
install.packages("aPackage",repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

So just add the repos part. You could of course also just install the package before usage and remove the install.packages line completely from your rmarkdown.